# pg_search trigram extension not working

Tags: pg-search, trigram

Rails5, i have it installed on database

```
pg_trgm       | 1.1     | public     | text similarity measurement and index searching based on trigrams)
```

and in the initializer :

```
PgSearch.multisearch_options = {
  :using => [:tsearch, :trigram],
}
```

i've tried it with only :trigram (not :tsearch), doesn't work, even after db:reset and rake pg_search:multisearch:rebuild[AllModels].

Am I missing a step?

Comment: :tsearch works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of pg_search.

Trigram search requires the `pg_trgm` extension.

See the [pg_search README](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#trigram-trigram-search) and [the wiki page for Installing PostgreSQL Extensions](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search/wiki/Installing-PostgreSQL-Extensions) for more details.